# extract text informations from many subfolders

Tags: bash

I'm looking to extract informations from subfolders.
I have a folder containing several folders containing several folders with text file information.

I've done something like this, but it works only when text files have different names (otherwise files with same names are erased by the most recent ones):

```
mkdir target_directory
pwd=`pwd`
find $pwd . -name \*.txt -exec cp {} target_directory \;
cd target_directory
cat *.txt > all-info
rm *.txt
```

I was thinking to had directory to the name of extracted files. How can I do that?

Maybe there is a smarter way?

Thank you!

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear. Do you just try to concatenate all your `*.txt` files, in any order, to a single file named `target_directory/all-info`? If yes, why not just `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; > /tmp/all-info; mkdir -p target_directory; mv /tmp/all-info target_directory`? Or something similar?

Comment: it works, thanks! Your command is simpler and more efficient than mine. Add your comment to answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to concatenate all `*.txt` files in `target_directory/all-info` then just use `cat {}` in the `exec` action of your `find` command and redirect the output:

```
$ mkdir -p target_directory
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; > target_directory/all-info
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
mkdir -p target_directory
find . -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} >> target_directory/all-info \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Man-pages of `cp` mention:

```
-n, --no-clobber
       do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)
```

So I think your solution (only the `find` part) should be:

```
find $pwd . -name \*.txt -exec cp -n {} target_directory \;
```